# How to celebrate birthdays as per Panchanga if births had taken place in Adhika Masa?

Tags: tradition, astrology, calendar, panchang

How do I celebrate birthday as per Panchanga, if we are born in [Adhika Masa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adhik_Maas)? For example, my son is born in Adhika Vaishaka, but this year there is no Adhika for Vaishaka.

Answer (score 1):

Can celebrate birth day in respective Nija masa (moon month). No need to wait for adhika masa in next coming years. Same thing applies to birth day on february 29. make a note of the tithi and masa (Moon month) and celebrate every year.